# Meaning of a Return type of this function in C++

Tags: c++

I have picked up an open source lib (libbitcoin.)

Would I like to have the explanation of the signature of this function?

```
static const char* symbol()
{
    return "fetch-balance";
}
```

Comment: It returns a pointer to constant characters, in other words a constant string.

Comment: static const char[]* ...? wasn't that more clear ?

Comment: @Gilad Reich It's a free function, not a member function. Static here is about linkage, meaning the function is only available inside this translation unit. And please think once more about the rest of your comment - there are several factual mistakes. For example, the `const` is applied to the return value, not the function. `char *` does not inherently mean "string". Etc.

Comment: You can't learn to program in `C++` by pasting random bits of code you encounter into a question. You should read a text and work from that. These come recommended. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will return pointer of char type that points to the starting address of the string "fetch-balance" i.e address of 'f'.

Comment: ... to the first character, this make sense.

Answer (score 0):

a static function that returns constant pointer to char, it returns the memory address of the first character of the returned string.

Comment: No. The `static` keyword is applied to the function, not the return type. The return type is `const char*`

Comment: true, sorry! thanks for noticing.